CircleCI filters stopped working without changes in config.yml file
Having this CircleCI setup in config.yml:
any_releasable: &any_releasable
  filters:
    tags:
      only: /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+/
    branches:
      ignore: /.*/

We're able to execute a continuous-deployment job when a new tag with semantic versioning is created:
  continuous-deployment:
    jobs:
      - build_release:
          <<: *any_releasable
      - notify_slack_qa_release:
          <<: *any_releasable
          context:
            - slack-secrets
          version: << pipeline.git.tag >>
          channel: ${SLACK_RELEASE_CHANNEL}
          requires:
            - build_release

That has been working without any problem so far, but this morning stopped working, because every new commit to any branch is triggering continuous-deployment workflow and failing, because there is no version parameter (which makes sense, because there is no tag).
Error calling workflow: 'continuous-deployment'
Error calling job: 'notify_slack_qa_release'
Unknown variable(s): version

I've looked into the most recent changes from CircleCI changelog, but I couldn't see anything relevant to this issue.
How should we be sure that this continuous-deployment is only executed when there is a new tag (with semantic versioning format) pushed to GitHub?

Fixed with ${CIRCLE_TAG:-0.0.0} instead, but leaving the question unanswered since we don't really understand the root of the fix
